# error while fetching empty column from database in iphone

Tags: iphone

i wnant to fetch the data fromt the database but getting error when i try to get the empty column... 
i used the following code to do it..
NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
so if my second column is empty than i get exception

Comment: have got the solution to do this...

NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text_check(compiledStatement, 2)];


const unsigned char *sqlite3_column_text_check(sqlite3_stmt* stmt, int iCol){
 const unsigned char *val = sqlite3_column_text(stmt,iCol);
 if(val==nil)
  return (unsigned char *)"";
 else
  return val;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put the condition to check the value:

```
NSString *aDescription = nil;
if((char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2) != NULL)
{
      aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
}
```

Now the it will not generate the exception.